# Gnucobol compiles .cob to .c failed to pass compiler of clang

Tags: clang, gnucobol

I was trying to compile hello.cob to hello.c:

```
$ ls
hello.cob
$ cobc -x -C hello.cob
$ ls
hello.c  hello.c.h  hello.c.l.h  hello.cob
```

But `clang` failed to compile hello.c to executable file:

```
$ clang hello.c
/tmp/hello-479acf.o: In function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `cob_init'
hello.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `cob_stop_run'
/tmp/hello-479acf.o: In function `sampleCOBOL_':
hello.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `cob_module_global_enter'
hello.c:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `cob_display'
hello.c:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `cob_stop_run'
hello.c:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `cob_check_version'
hello.c:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `cob_set_cancel'
hello.c:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `cob_fatal_error'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is hello.cob (can be compiled by `cobc -x hello.cob`):

```
      IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
      PROGRAM-ID. sampleCOBOL.
      PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      DISPLAY "Hello World!".
      STOP RUN.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure clang doesn't fail to compile the C source as you don't ave any C compiler warnings or errors.
It cannot link the generated object file because you didn't told clang to link against libcob and there is no "magic" for clang to know where to find its symbols. Adding `-lcob` to your `clang` invocation may be enough already.

If you want to know how `cobc` invokes the compiler/linker add `-v` to your `cobc` invocation.

Note: if this version of `cobc` was built with `gcc` it defaults to use `gcc`, too. You can see this with `cobc --info` which also shows if any of the built-in commands is override by environment variables.
Additional note: `cobc` does not only call a C compiler/linker, it also generates C code specific for the compiler it was built with. The most important part concerning the C generation is `-f[no-]computed-goto`, just in case the C compiler complains (which it doesn't in your case).

Comment: it says "hello.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to \`cob_module_global_enter'" after adding `-lcob`, though other references are found.

Comment: I'd assume you have more than one version of libcob installed... in any case: do `cobc -v hello.cob`, see what compiler option `cobc` uses and try the same.